# Display tkinter scale value realtime

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a scale in Tkinter using the code below:

```py
demo = ttk.Labelframe(col2, text='Demo', padding=(15, 10))
demo.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes', pady=(10, 0))
epoch = ttk.Frame(demo)
epoch.pack(fill='x', padx=(20, 0), pady=(5, 0))

ttk.Label(epoch, text='10 epoch').pack(side='left')
ttk.Label(epoch, text='1000 epoch').pack(side='right')
ttk.Scale(epoch, value=990, from_=10, to=1000).pack(side='left', fill='x', expand='yes', padx=(30, 0))
```

I want to have a label that displays the value of the scale at its current position in real time right below it. How should I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you want to place the label right below the handle of your Slider/Scale widget. This can be easily achieved using the `place` on a `Label`. To get the `x, y` coordinates of the handle use the `scale.coords`.

Minimal example:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter  as tk


def update_lbl(*args):

    x, _ = scale.coords()  # gets handle x position
    y, h = scale.winfo_y(), scale.winfo_height() # get the widgets y position and height
    scale_lbl.place(x=x, y=h+y) 


root = tk.Tk()

val = tk.IntVar(root)

val.set(0)

scale_lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=val)

scale = ttk.Scale(root, variable=val, from_=10, to=1000)
scale.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand='yes', padx=(30, 0))
scale.bind('<Configure>', lambda ev: scale.after(1, update_lbl))

val.trace('w', update_lbl)

root.mainloop()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using the `command` option instead? Even then, why use `after(1,func)`? It is almost same as `func()`.

Comment: @CoolCloud there is nothing wrong with using the command option. Now by using the `IntVar` and trace method I can be sure the label will always have the same value as the slider value. Coming to your second question. If you press the maximize button the label position will not be updated correctly hence, I use the after method to give a very small delay.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `IntVar()`

```
scale_val=IntVar()
ttk.Scale(epoch, value=990,variable=scale_val, from_=10, to=1000).pack(side='left', fill='x', expand='yes', padx=(30, 0))
lbl_val=ttk.Label(epoch)
lbl_val.pack(side='bottom') #=== Set it according to your will
```

Then you can trace the variable:

```
def trace_method(*args):
    x=scale_val.get()
    lbl_val.config(text=f'{x} %')
scale_val.trace('w',trace_method)
```

Comment: Why? It has `command` option. Just `command=trace_method` should work